# Odoo 8 - How to update a Many2one field value?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8

I'm trying to make module that gives employees visa balance.
What I'm trying to do is that when a visa number is assigned to an employee it changes the counter used_visa to be increased by 1.
so my question is how to update the counter which is in 'visa.balance.line' model when a visa number is selected in 'hr.employee' model

Here's my code:

```
class hr_visa_balance(models.Model):
_name = "hr.visa.balance"
_rec_name = "visa_no"

visa_no = fields.Char("Visa Number")
approval_date = fields.Date('Approval Date')
visa_line_ids = fields.One2many('visa.balance.line', 'visa_line_id', 'Visa Balance Details')


class visa_balance_line(models.Model):
_name = 'visa.balance.line'
_rec_name = "visa_line_id"

profession = fields.Char()
gender = fields.Selection([('m','Male'),('f','Female')], 'Gender')
country_id = fields.Many2one('res.country', 'Nationality')
available_visa = fields.Integer('Available')
used_visa = fields.Integer('Used')
visa_line_id = fields.Many2one('hr.visa.balance', 'Visa Balance Details')


class hr_employee(models.Model):
_inherit = 'hr.employee',

visa_line = fields.Many2one('visa.balance.line', 'Visa Balance Details')


@api.onchange('visa_line')
def onchange_visa_no(self):
    ~ code here ~
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all i am not getting your structure,
i think in employee you have to choose many2one of "hr.visa.balance" object,
and you are choosing "visa.balance.line"

now what you have to do:

give one many2one of hr.visa.balance" in hr.employee and on on_change of visa_no you have to write logic,

Note: you directly can count visa balance in "hr.visa.balance" this object.

no need to take this field in visa.balance.line.